# Create a definition query for groups of layers: Is it possible?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcgis-9.3, modelbuilder

I have a large number of groups created, with each group having many layers.  I have looked for a way to set a definition query for all the layers in each group but haven't found anything.  Is it even possible, maybe with model builder or python?  I have ArcMap 9.3 and 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function should handle this.

```
import arpcy
def definitionByGroup(definition = "", groupname = "", mxd = "CURRENT"):
    #create layer list for current map document
    layerlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd))
    for layer in layerlist:
        if layer.isFeatureLayer:
            groups = layer.longName.split('\\')
            if groupname == "" and layer.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
                layer.definitionQuery = definition
            if len(groups) > 1 and groupname in groups and layer.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
                layer.definitionQuery = definition
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Copy paste into the arcpy window and it will be available.

Usage:

Change definition to "OBJECTID = 1" for all feature layers in group "Test" in the current map

```
definitionByGroup("OBJECTID = 1", "Test")
```

Same change, but in the map stored at "C:\test.mxd"

```
definitionByGroup("OBJECTID = 1", "Test", "C:\text.mxd")
```

Clear definitions on all feature layers in group "Test"

```
definitionByGroup("", "Test")
```

Set definition on all feature layers in current map

```
definitionByGroup("OBJECTID = 1")
```

Clear all definitions in current map

```
definitionByGroup()
```

Clear all definitions in map at "C:\text.mxd"

```
definitionByGroup("", "", "C:\text.mxd")
```

This function will also scan nested groups, matching on any layer of the group nesting.

If you want this to be an importable script into ArcMap, save this to a .py file in the pythonpath. e.g. save as definitionByGroup.py and then import and use with:

```
import definitionByGroup
definitionByGroup.definitionByGroup(...)
```