# add definition query to layers in a group

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python-2.6, definition-query

I'm trying to develop a python code that will apply the same definition query to all layers in a specified group.  I currently have a working code that will apply a definition query to all layers in the Table of Contents, but unfortunately I need it to apply the syntax to a specific group of layers. Any ideas?

I've seen this post:

[Create a definition query for groups of layers: Is it possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/create-a-definition-query-for-groups-of-layers-is-it-possible)

But when I set it up specific to my mxd project, nothing happens.

```
import arcpy

#Variables to form query syntax
#-------------------------------------------
#field in Attribute table
field = 'Country \n'
queryField = '"%s"' % field.strip()   #add double quotes field (for query syntax)
#value in specified field
value = "'Canada'"
#concatenate query syntax
queryStr = str(queryField) + "=" + str(value)
#--------------------------------------------
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"): 
        lyr.definitionQuery = queryStr
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()       
del mxd
```

Comment: How are you running your script? It must be run as a script tool or from the ArcMap Python window to be run in-process, which allows the "CURRENT" map document to be modified.

Comment: Just running it in the python window for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I got it, thanks anyways!
It's a little bit more elegant now.

```
import arcpy

#Variables to form defintion query
field = '"Country"'
value = "'Canada'"
#concatenate query syntax
queryStr = str(field) + "=" + str(value)
#Specify the MXD project (CURRENT), dataframe (Layers)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
#Apply defintion query to specified layer group (Test)
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Test", df)[0]:
    if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"): 
        lyr.definitionQuery = queryStr
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()       
del mxd
```