# Group and export to pdf based on an attribute field using DDP - Python Script

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, export, pdf, data-driven-pages

Using Python, I want to export a map series. Each series needs to be **grouped based on an attribute** field which is not being used in DDP settings (page num, page index etc...).

For example: my shapefile RoadName.shp has a field called **RoadType**.  Now when I ask my DDP to export maps, it should **group diff RoadTypes** into one single (multipage) pdf.

Any quick solution please?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to group individual RoadTypes, not coalesce them together?

Comment: Have you tried setting the definition query for each category of RoadType? This works manually - if you refresh the DDP after setting the features definition query.

Comment: @M.B. If you wish, you can add your code as a new answer, instead of heavily editing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should achieve what you have asked (not tested):

```
import arcpy
import os

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\temp\mymap.mxd")
output_folder = r"C:\temp"
ddp_lyr = mxd.dataDrivenPages.indexLayer
pdf_field = "RoadType"

#Get a list of unique values to group by
pdf_list = set([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ddp_lyr,pdf_field)])

for pdfName in pdf_list:
    finalPdf = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(os.path.join(output_folder,pdfName + ".pdf"))
    for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
        mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
        cur = str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue(pdf_field))
        if cur == pdfName:
            tempPdf = os.path.join(output_folder,"temp_" + cur + str(i) + ".pdf")
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, tempPdf)
            finalPdf.appendPages(tempPdf)
            os.remove(tempPdf)
    finalPdf.saveAndClose()
    del finalPdf, tempPdf
```

The code is not optimised, so it loops over all the data driven pages for each unique value in the list. With some rearranging, it may be better to first export all the pdfs, then check the filenames for the unique value and group them accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the code with `os.remove(tempPdf)` to delete the file after it has been added to the final pdf.

Comment: Great Arabella.  You are a superstar.

Comment: Please post your code as an alternative answer, as the comments are not the place for it. If you are going to use this script as a script tool, you need to set both the `mxd` and `output_folder` as input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of psuedo code and a bit of code rearranged from [another stack exchange answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28553/add-definition-query-to-layers-in-a-group):

```
roadtypes = list of the unique values in RoadType field
field = "RoadType"
#Loop through the road types
for type in roadtypes:
    queryStr = str("{0}" + " = " + '{1}').format(field, type)

    #Specify the MXD project (CURRENT), dataframe (Layers)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

    #Apply defintion query to specified layer group (Test)
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Test", df)[0]:
        if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"): 
            lyr.definitionQuery = queryStr
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()      
    #Export map series
    #arcpy.exportToPDF()
```

Comment: Thanks Mwil. Your code comes with an error but it must be me doing something wrong here. Arabella, code works fine.