# Exporting DDP to multiple multi-page pdf files

Tags: arcpy, export, arcgis-10.4, data-driven-pages

In ArcMap 10.4 I have an index layer in DDP enabled mxd. The index layer has 50 unique Name values (used as the PageName in DDP) but there are more rows with the same Name value providing different scales, spatial extents etc. I'm looking for an ArcPy script to export pdf files with all pages of the same Name.

Example:

```
Name   Scale
A      5000
A      600
B      25000
B      5000
B      2500
...
```

Result:

```
A.pdf (2 pages)
B.pdf (3 pages)
...
```

Would you be so kind to provide some hint? Apparently, I'm stuck in the process of correctly defining the 'for' loop.

So far I tried to use the modified code from Cindy Jayakumar https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71702/93026, which was closest to what I found:

```
import arcpy
import os

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
output_folder = r"C:\temp"
ddp_lyr = mxd.dataDrivenPages.indexLayer
pdf_field = "Name"

#Get a list of unique values to group by
pdf_list = set([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ddp_lyr,pdf_field)])

for pdfName in pdf_list:
    arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(os.path.join(output_folder,pdfName + "_inv.pdf"))
    for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
        mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
        cur = str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue(pdf_field))
        if cur == pdfName:
            tempPdf = os.path.join(output_folder,"temp_" + cur + str(i) + ".pdf")
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, tempPdf)
            finalPdf.appendPages(tempPdf)
            os.remove(tempPdf)
    finalPdf.saveAndClose()
    del finalPdf, tempPdf
```

The above code does what I need to some extent as from some reason does not export the pdf files for all unique values in the "Name" field. I was not able to identify why some have been exported and some not. I know there is much easier way to do this as 2 years ago I already had the code working (though not saving it).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What have you tried?  A good question should include some degree of research and attempt.  Please [edit] your question to include any code you've attempted, and details on what happens when you try it including any error messages in full.  There are many Q&As here regarding arcpy for exporting PDFs from DDP - that would be a good place to search first.

Comment: Once you have a script that mostly do what you want, then come back and ask focused questions regarding anything that doesn't work.

Comment: The two dead links you provided were just mirrors of the question you got your code from - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71631/group-and-export-to-pdf-based-on-an-attribute-field-using-ddp-python-script

Comment: Can you please expand on what you mean by "it omits some Names"?  Can you provide a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1):

At the end (and after some hours of debugging) I was able to create simple code which does the export.

I'll set another example:

```
Sites   River
A       Nile
A       Nile
A       Nile
B       Nile
B       Nile
C       Amazon
C       Amazon
...
```

Code

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
indexLayer = ddp.indexLayer
output_folder = r"C:\temp"
select = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(indexLayer, 'Sites'))

for site in select:
    where_clause = '"Sites" = ' + "'%s'" %site
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (indexLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
    riv = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(indexLayer, 'River'))
    ddp.exportToPDF(r"C:\Temp\\" + str(site) + "_" + str(riv)[7:-3] + ".pdf", "SELECTED" )
del mxd
```

The stripping parameter `str(riv)[7:-3]` in the definition of the exported pdf name had to be added to delete the 'extra' characters "set(['*'])".

Before deletion:

```
A_set([u'Nile']).pdf
B_set([u'Nile']).pdf
C_set([u'Amazon']).pdf
```

After deletion:

```
A_Nile.pdf
B_Nile.pdf
C_Amazon.pdf
```

I don't know why variable `riv` returns this extended format, while variable `site` is pure string value, however, the script works fine now.