# Exporting groups of PDF based on Orientation

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, pdf, data-driven-pages

I am trying to create a map book with two different orientations. The part I am currently stuck on is for the loop to go through the table and export groups of the same orientation. an example of the table is like:

**_OR|Page_Num**

Portrait|1
Portrait|2
Portrait|3
Landscape|4
Landscape|5
Landscape|6

and would like to have it exported as "Portrait 1-3.pdf"(I have another mxd for landscape so I would just make a quick edit so it works for landscape instead of portrait) so that I could combine the smaller groups in sequential order using bluebeam. I currently am using code I found on [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231299/exporting-ddp-to-multiple-multi-page-pdf-files) that selects all portrait or landscape and exports them, but would be ideal if I could break it up.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
indexLayer = ddp.indexLayer
output_folder = r"C:\Users\JAlmeida\Downloads\Pdf"
select = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(indexLayer, '_OR'))

for _OR in select:
    where_clause = '"_OR" = ' + "'%s'" %_OR
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (indexLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
        ddp.exportToPDF(str(_OR) + ".pdf", "SELECTED" )
del mxd
```