# Writing Python Def Query for multiple layers

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, definition-query

I have Three layers in a .mxd, all three layers have a common value I can use, but a different Label in each Layer. 
As an example, the Value I want to use is "100"

In Layer A, the Value is in [Name]
In Layer B, the Value is in [Series]
In Layer C, the Value is in [SeriesName]

The Def Query for Layer A is "Name = '100'"
The Def Query for Layer B is "Series = '100'"
The Def Query for Layer C is "SeriesName LIKE '100-%'"

What I am looking for is a python script that will allow me to enter in the number,
and apply that number to all three Def Queries.

Answer (score 3):

I hope following function will help you. Just pass the mxd path and query string to the function and it will open the mxd with Def queries on three layers.

def mxd_Select(mxd_Path, Qry_str):

```
    def sql_Cosm(str): # cosmatic string for proper sql commond.
        cosm_Strg = ''
        for str in str.split(","): # for sql cosmatic
            if cosm_Strg == '':
                cosm_Strg = "'"+str+"'"
            else:
                cosm_Strg = cosm_Strg+",'"+str+"'"
        return(cosm_Strg)

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_Path)       

    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd): # listing all feature classes.
        if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY") is True:
            if lyr.name == 'Layer A':
                lyr.definitionQuery = "\"Name\" = ("+sql_Cosm(Qry_str)+")"     
            if lyr.name == 'Layer B':
                lyr.definitionQuery = "\"Series\" = ("+sql_Cosm(Qry_str)+")"
            if lyr.name == 'Layer C':
                lyr.definitionQuery = "\"SeriesName\" = ("+sql_Cosm(Qry_str+'-%')+")"

    mxd.save() # saving mxd
    del mxd
    # opening mxd in ArcMap
    os.startfile(mxd_Path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general workflow to consider:

1. Create a [python script tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_a_script_tool/001500000006000000/) to take in the search value
2. Use [ListLayers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000002n000000) method to gather and focus on the three layers you want to search against.
3. Iterate through layer list from step 2 and call each layer into a query buuilder function using a [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000) to check if the search value exists or not in the focus layer
4. If the value is found, from step 3 return a query string and reference it to the layer definition property, e.g. `lyr.definitionQuery = queryStr` (example of the definition query portion may be found from this [Q/A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28553/add-definition-query-to-layers-in-a-group))
5. Finally, refresh your active view, e.g. `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()`

Comment: Just to show how new I am to ARC and python in General, I am using 9.3.1 for the moment.  Is the syntax/layout for the commands given in 10.2 the same for 9.3.1?  Thanks!

Comment: The arcpy module suite came out in version v10.  You will have to consider using ArcObjects, vb script, or creating a ModelBuilder script, or better upgrading to v10.  I'm not sure there is a easy way of defining a definition query using vb script or ModelBuilder though apart from just creating a new queried layer.

Comment: @artwork21, just for clarification, [import arcgisscripting](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.1/index.cfm?id=1926&pid=1924&topicname=Creating%20and%20debugging%20geoprocessing%20scripts&) (the predecessor to arcpy) was available as early as 9.1, however, that only contains references to Geoprocessing tools, not interfacing with the TOC/definition queries.  In order to interface with the TOC/definition query through Python, you are correct, the user will need to upgrade to 10.x and work with arcpy.