# Apply a definition query to a Layer Group

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-pro, group-layer, indexerror

I'm trying to apply a definition query to multiple layers within a Layer Group by using the following script where I would simply change the values for my 'SUBCODE' field:

```
import arcpy

#Variables to form defintion query
field = '"SUBCODE"'
values = "'1152','1153'"
#concatenate query syntax
queryStr = str(field) + "=" + str(value)
#Specify the aprx project (CURRENT), dataframe (Layers)
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps("Map_3D")[0]
#Apply defintion query to specified layer group 
for lyr in m.listLayers( "3D Layers")[0]:
    if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"): 
    lyr.definitionQuery = queryStr
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()       
del aprx
```

This is the error I'm receiving when I run this in Arcpy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

There's a similar question posted on [SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28553/add-definition-query-to-layers-in-a-group) that applies the same logic of applying a definition query to a Layer Group, however I'm using ArcGIS Pro and the post refers to ArcMap.  There are some migration from arcpy.mapping to ArcGIS Pro I'm having trouble with - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/migratingfrom10xarcpymapping.htm

Here's an illustration of my Layer Group:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!  I've added the asterisk at the end of "3D Layers*" and came up with the following error:                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Here's what I get when I print with: print(m.listlayers()) -    
                                                                                       
 print(m.listlayers())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'listlayers'
                                                                                                                            I've added an illustration of my Layer Group in my original post.  Hopefully the logic in my script applies to this type of Layer Group?

Comment: made the change and this is the error I've received - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: 'Layer' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot list layer groups with listlayers and you do not want to list groups because you cannot apply a definition query to a layer group. You want to list individual layers and then apply the definition query to each of them so change line 12 to:

```
for lyr in m.listLayers("CONDO*"):
```